# c# excel com interop: moving charts in between sheets

Tags: c#, excel, exception, com, interop

I have generated a workbook using the c# excel com interop. I have Sheets with just data, and accompanying charts. The charts and sheets are on seperate excel tabs within the workbook.

During generation of the charts and sheets, all the sheets are grouped first while the group of charts is second in the tab list. I would like to put the individual chart tabs immediately after their corresponding sheet tabs. This is what I have so far:

```
    private void move_charts_into_position(Excel.Workbook workbook)
    {
        int tab_count = 1;
        foreach (Excel.Chart chart_tab in workbook.Charts)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(chart_tab.Index.ToString()); //prints chart 1 here
            if (tab_count + 1 > workbook.Sheets.Count)
                chart_tab.Move(workbook.Sheets[tab_count], Type.Missing);
            else
                chart_tab.Move(workbook.Sheets[tab_count], workbook.Sheets[tab_count + 1]); //fails at first iteration here

            tab_count+=2;
        }
    }
```

This generates an *Unable to get the Move property of the Chart class* COM exception at runtime. I think its likely because the Sheets collection is being passed as an arg for the Move.

Any general suggestions that could help my understanding for these objects? I have a hunch I could employ some casting tricks to get this to work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, charts are placed into the sheets container. I move charts into position by grabbing the charts from the sheets array in the workbook.